# Codeception & Symfony - run Doctrine migrations before tests

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, codeception

I have a Symfony 4 application and Doctrine with Doctrine migrations. I'm introducing Codeception for running API tests, and need to run migrations before the tests run. Since I'm using the [Doctrine2 module](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Doctrine2) I don't really want to be also including the [DB module](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Db.html) as it's not needed for the tests and would require configuring the test database in two different locations.

I am using the [Symfony module](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Symfony) currently, and I noticed that the [Laravel module](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Laravel5) has a `run_database_migrations` configuration option.

What is the best way to handle running the Doctrine migrations command in a Symfony app prior to the tests? (`bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate -n` is the specific command).

---

**Edit** I've got a solution that, although it works, is nowhere near ideal. By using [Codeception Customisation](https://codeception.com/docs/08-Customization#events) I've created the following extension that basically manually `exec`s the underlying Symfony commands.

```
class DatabaseMigrationExtension extends Extension
{
    public static $events = [
        Events::SUITE_BEFORE => 'beforeSuite',
    ];

    public function beforeSuite(SuiteEvent $e)
    {
        echo(exec('bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force') . PHP_EOL);
        echo(exec('bin/console doctrine:database:create') . PHP_EOL);
        echo(exec('bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate -n') . PHP_EOL);
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 2** The goal of this is basically to replicate similar functionality to what the Codeception DB module does, which allows you to provide an SQL dump of a database that it automatically uses in the tests, but instead use Doctrine migrations to handle the DB. - https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Db#sql-data-dump

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I spent a while trying a couple of different ways to achieve this. I initially used [RunProcess](https://codeception.com/extensions#RunProcess) however this seemed to cause sporadic issues with the DB being deleted and not recreated, despite using the sleep configuration. I ended up just updating the existing extension to use the CLI module instead, and it works as desired (without having to create scripts or run multiple commands) and without having to use `exec`.

**Final extension;**

```
class DatabaseMigrationExtension extends Extension
{
    public static $events = [
        Events::SUITE_BEFORE => 'beforeSuite',
    ];

    public function beforeSuite()
    {
        try {
            /** @var \Codeception\Module\Cli $cli */
            $cli = $this->getModule('Cli');

            $this->writeln('Recreating the DB...');
            $cli->runShellCommand('bin/console doctrine:database:drop --if-exists --force');
            $cli->seeResultCodeIs(0);
            $cli->runShellCommand('bin/console doctrine:database:create');
            $cli->seeResultCodeIs(0);

            $this->writeln('Running Doctrine Migrations...');
            $cli->runShellCommand('bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction');
            $cli->seeResultCodeIs(0);

            $this->writeln('Test database recreated');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->writeln(
                sprintf(
                    'An error occurred whilst rebuilding the test database: %s',
                    $e->getMessage()
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**and registered;**

```
// codeception.yml
extensions:
    enabled:
        - \DatabaseMigrationExtension
```

**Output (`-vv` or higher also displays the output of the DB & Migration commands);**
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you be targeting a database that is specifically meant for testing? With argument `--env=test`?

Comment: @Starwave yes -- I was, hence wanting to rebuild it each time

Answer (score 2):

I always create a bash script to do this, or a Makefile.

## bash command

My `./runtests.sh` scripts contains

```
#!/bin/bash
./bin/console command:for:migrations
./bin/phpunit
```

## Makefile

Same with Makefile

```
.FOO: testsuite
testsuite:
    ./runtests.sh
```

or

```
.FOO: testsuite
testsuite:
    ./bin/console command:for:migrations
    ./bin/phpunit
```

## why I prefer Makefile

Recently I added this script in my .bash_profile that allow me to autocomplete from bash all target made in makefile (very easy because you dont need anymore to remember all commands, but just `make` and `tab`).

> complete -W "`grep -oE '^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+:([^=]|$)' Makefile | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$//'`" make

Thus, .. you can create target like:

- runtests
- runtests_with_fixtures
- migrations
- runtests_with_migrations
- ...

and so on

My suggestion is to create your custom and easy way to run commands.

---

Here a way to run all or just one command usgin make

```
.FOO: dropforce
dropforce:
    bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force

.FOO: dbcreate
dbcreate:
    bin/console doctrine:database:create

.FOO: migrate
migrate:
    bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate

.FOO: suite
suite: dropforce dbcreate migrate
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer - I'm happy to progress this way as a fallback but ideally I want the handling of the database (create, migrate) to be handled by the test suite, not externally as the test suite is already acting in the test environment (not dev) and handles cleanup/teardown. The hacky solution I have above does this for me, so running the tests doesn't require any prior setup, it's all handled in the test command and sets up the DB as per the test env variables under which the tests themselves also run.

Answer (score 1):

With Codeception 4 you can do it without Cli module:

```
$symfony = $this->getModule('Symfony');

$symfony->runSymfonyConsoleCommand('doctrine:database:drop',['--if-exists'=>true, '--force'=>true]);
$symfony->runSymfonyConsoleCommand('doctrine:database:create');
$symfony->runSymfonyConsoleCommand('doctrine:migrations:migrate', ['--no-interaction'=>true]);
```